# In c++ how do I successfully chain classes together in the following example?

Tags: c++, c++11

In c++ how do I successfully chain classes together in the following example?

```
Clock timer;

std::cout << timer.getElapsedTime().inSeconds();
std::cout << timer.getElapsedTime().inMilliseconds();
```

How do I write the code successfully?

```
class ElapsedTime
{
private:
    double _start;

public :
    ElapsedTime(double start)
    {
        _start = start;
    }
    double inSeconds() const
    {
        return (std::clock() - _start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }

    double inMilliseconds() const
    {
        return ((std::clock() - _start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000;
    }
};


class Clock
{
private:
    std::clock_t _start;
    double _duration;

public:

    Clock()
    {
        _start = std::clock();
    }

    ElapsedTime getElapsedTime() const {
        return ElapsedTime(_start);
    }

    double reset()
    {
        _duration = (std::clock() - _start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        _start = std::clock();
        return _duration;
    }

};
```

edit: made the suggested changes by pm100

Although the class chain still returns a value like .7e-05

and if I try to use const in the following manner I get a segmentation fault

```
ElapsedTime const& getElapsedTime() const {
        return ElapsedTime(_start);
```

Comment: why dont u make inSeconds and inMIliseconds members of the clock class?

Comment: As I undestand, you want to create a special class which will store some value of time and will allow you to get time in seconds and in milliseconds, yes?

Comment: When you're done with learning about this, may I suggest `#include <chrono>` ?

Comment: Thank you for your other suggestions but i specifically want to learn how to chain classes together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to make it work this way, which is odd. You need a constructor for ElapsedTime that takes `start`

```
class ElapsedTime
{
     double _start;
  public :
     ElapsedTime(double start)
     { 
        _start = start;
    }
```

(use _start in the rest of the code)

Then in clock

```
   ElapsedTime getElapsedTime() const {
        return ElapsedTime(start);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer... although when I compile the code the class chain returns something like .9e-05... It looks like getElapsedTime() is returning the value of the 'ElapsedTime' default contructor??

Comment: you now have a different question, ask a new question with all the code posted

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "start" is declared within the scope of your class Clock. It isn't defined within the scope of your class ElapsedTime.

Why don't you define a method ElapsedTime in your Clock class rather than using 2 classes?

Answer (score 1):

If I were writing this code, I probably would not make `ElapsedTime` its own class. I think I would just add `getElapsedTimeInSeconds()` and `getElapsedTimeInMilliseconds()` to the `Clock` class, like so:

```
class Clock
{
public:
    Clock()
    {
        start = std::clock();
    }

    double getElapsedTimeInSeconds() const
    {
        return (std::clock() - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }

    double getElapsedTimeInMilliseconds() const
    {
        return getElapsedTimeInSeconds() * 1000;
    }

    double reset()
    {
        duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        start = std::clock();
        return duration;
    }

protected:
    std::clock_t start;

private:
    double duration;
};
```

and then the main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    Clock timer;

    std::cout << timer.getElapsedTimeInSeconds() << std::endl;
    std::cout << timer.getElapsedTimeInMilliseconds() << std::endl;
}
```